# How to categorize data based on values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If all employees have scores less than 3, the risk is high, if I have one employee with a score of 3 or 4, the risk is medium, if we have several employees with a score of 3 or 4, the risk is low

for example:

Table:

| Employees | Technology 1 | Technology 2 | Technology 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Doug | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| Henry | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| Jo | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Fren | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Charlize | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Mary | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Michael | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| Klint | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Silvester | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Output Risk | Low | Medium | High |

Comment: I add table for better understanding

Comment: I need to have a risk assessment based on the input of the rating. If in the field from A2 to A 10 I have one 3 status MEDIUM, and if I don't have 3 status "LOW" and if I have at least one 3 and one 4 status "HIGH"

Comment: When I say 3 or 4 I mean value

Comment: I'll try to provide better explanation. Give me some time

Comment: I have a table of employees and technologies. I need to rate them, based on the rating to have a technology risk assessment

Comment: If all employees have scores less than 3, the risk is high, if I have one employee with a score of 3 or 4, the risk is medium, if we have several employees with a score of 3 or 4, the risk is low

Comment: This is my first question so I'm still trying to figure out how to do it right

Comment: Is the post clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use COUNTIF:

```
=LET(
    rng,B2:B11,
    fr,COUNTIF(rng,4),
    th,COUNTIF(rng,3),
    IF(fr+th=1,"medium",IF(th+fr>1,"low","high")))
```

[image]

For older versions:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B11,4)+COUNTIF(B2:B11,3)=1,"medium",IF(COUNTIF(B2:B11,3)+COUNTIF(B2:B11,4)>1,"low","high"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the badly asked question.

Comment: Is it possible to show how many employees have a rating of 3 and how many have a rating of 4 for a given technology

Comment: The COUNTIF parts of the second formula will give you that.

Comment: If this answered you question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative approach, works with `MS365`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B12`

```
=LET(a,B2:D11,BYCOL(a,LAMBDA(x,
LET(y,SUM(COUNTIFS(x,{3,4})),IFS(y=1,"Medium",y>1,"Low",y=0,"High")))))
```

---

**Non-MS365** - Users might need to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

```
=IF(
    SUM(
        COUNTIFS(
            B2:B11, {3, 4}
        )
    ) = 1,
    "Medium",
    IF(
        SUM(
            COUNTIFS(
                B2:B11, {3, 4}
            )
        ) > 1,
        "Low",
        "High"
    )
)
```

---

Alternative approaches, without using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> --> Using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B12`

```
=LET(
     a,B2:D11,
     b,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(a),,0),(a=3)+(a=4)),
     IFS(b=0,"High",b=1,"Medium",b>1,"Low"))
```

---